# Talend Open Studio : scripting languages versus Microsoft SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, talend

I have been trying to find out if Talend Open Studio has a scripting language. I hope that maybe it would be Perl or Python.
I have been using Microsoft SSIS ETL tool, and they have a Script-Component to handle more complex ETL tasks.
The SSIS Script-Component uses the languages C# and VB.NET as its scripting language.

Does Talend Open Studio have an equivalent to MS-SSIS Scripting Component.

I could not find much on the web on this.
The amount of material available for Talend Open Studio is very little.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talend (Open Studio or Entreprise editions) is built on Java, and enables you to implement complex tasks in Java using `tJava`, `tJavaRow` and `tJavaFlex` components, as well as custom Java routines. You can also build your own custom components using XML to describe components, and javajet to generate the actual Java code.
Earlier versions of Talend (up to version 4) had Perl support, but it's been deprecated.

Comment: Hi iMezouar, thanks for your reply. If it uses Java, is it just pure Java, or can you use other languages on the JVM, like Groovy, Scala, Kotlin, Jython. I hope its flexible enough to have these as well.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to compile a program written in one of the JVM languages into a jar and loading it as a library, but I'm not sure about this.. Maybe you could ask a question in the Java tag, I'm sure Java experts will answer you.

Comment: OK, thanks for this detail iMezouar, really appreciate it. I will mark your reply as the answer to this. Thanks again.